# Androidmanifest.xml PlayStore settings for Samsung GalaxyTab 4 series

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-manifest

I can't seem to get the Samsung GalaxyTab 4 7.0 to be included in the PlayStore list of compatible devices for my `Cordova` app, despite:

- using only `supports-screens`, not `compatible-screens`
- using `compatible-screens` instead of just `supports-screens`
- various combinations of `resizeable=true/false`, `anyDensity=true/false`
- removing ALL Cordova plugins and effectively bringing the required permissions to near zero
- toying the min- and targetSdkVersion versions, and the SDK Version used by Cordova
- adding either ALL possible `uses-feature/required=false` or just those you'd think make sense (hardware.telephony since it's a no-SIM/WIFI-only device)
- ^ now including `touchscreen` and `screen.portrait/landscape`
- removing the forced `screenOrientation="portrait"`
- including `tvdpi/213` in compatible-screens

(GalaxyTabs <4 are compatible though)

What am I missing?

Current `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10200" android:versionName="1.2.0" package="[removed]" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens
      android:anyDensity="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:resizeable="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
    />
    <application
      android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
          android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop"
          android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Cordova default here -->
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false" />
    <!-- With compat-screens added, there'd also be: -->
    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="213" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="213" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="213" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="213" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
</manifest>
```

### ----

`aapt dump badging app.apk`

```
package: name='[removed]' versionCode='10200' versionName='1.2.0'
application-label:'[removed]'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi-v4/icon.png'
application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/icon.png'
application: label='[removed]' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='[removed].CordovaApp'  label='[removed]' icon=''
sdkVersion:'18'
targetSdkVersion:'21'
uses-permission:'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.screen.landscape'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE','requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
main
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320'
```

Edit: Updated manifest, added aapt dump

### ----

Edit2:
It now - inexplicably - works with the above manifest (and variations thereof).
Must be black magic.

Comment: Did you had a look on the Google Play Console, when you upload your APK file, Google gives you a list a compatible devices. "you app is compatible with NNN devices", so you can get the details, and confirm you see the device you want.

Comment: Yep. That's where it says they're not compat.

Comment: @Flo Just to be sure, does it work if you remove the `supports-screens` and `compatible-screens` elements altogether?

Comment: I had no idea `supports-screens` could be omitted. Unfortunately, it does add a couple of devices to the list, but has no effect on the GT4.

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the whole compatible-screens section. As stated here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html , you should only use this as a last resort

**EDIT**

It might also help to add screenDensity="tvdpi" for large screens in your compatible-screens section. For instance, the first generation Nexus 7 has a tvdpi density.

Something else that might help is the aapt tool, for instance

```
./aapt dump badging YourApp.apk
```

Comment: Tried that also, no effect. And unfortunately the screen size attributes in `supports-screens` can only be used to exclude phones from tablet apps, not (large) tablets from phone apps; and right now I wouldn't want to allow >7" Tablets.

Comment: Perhaps the aapt tool might help you discover some incompatibility in the manifest declarations?

Comment: Right. I'd added 213/tvdpi at some point, but only for large screens. Unfortunately adding the others did nothing either. I've removed all compat-screens entries and the forced portrait layout and attached an aapt dump (which doesn't really show anything new unfortunately) in the OP.

Comment: Oh man that's a tricky one. You might want to also try adding the following 3 properties to your supports-screens section android:largestWidthLimitDp="1200" android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="1200" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320". Although I'm also doubting whether it will make a difference or not.

Comment: And another attempt might be <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" /> ?

Comment: All those did nothing either. But for some reason the manifest from last night works now and I have absolutely no idea how or why. I've awarded you the bounty anyway, thank you for your help (aapt tool in particular).